# IE 11 ignores width with display:flex child

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox

I currently trying to resolve an issue with `display: flex` and Internet Explorer 11. I have a table with a fixed width, which has a div with `display: flex` inside. This causes the table to get stretched in IE11. I tried to use the `flex-wrap` property, which does not change the behavior in IE at all, but brekas the layout in chrome, too. I broke down the code to the snippet below, which shows the issue, when you open it in IE11 and Chrome (or basically any other browser). Does anyone has an idea how to achieve the correct behavior of Chrome in IE11?

(Initial Snippet)

```css
table {
    width: 200px; 
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.flex {
   display:flex;
}

.icon:before {
   content: "✆";
}
```

```html
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <div class="flex">
            <span class="icon"></span>
            <span class="content">Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem Ipsum dolor and so on ...</span>
         </div>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

***Edit 1:*** *After trying both [Paulie_D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2802040/paulie-d) and [LGSon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2827823/lgson)'s answer, it causes the table to predefine the column widths, instaed of waiting for the actual content width, which causes some text overflows. I updated the Snippets below to show this. Was able to reproduce it with LGSons answer, currently digging deeper on Paulie_D's answer.*

```css
table {
    width:200px; 
    border: 1px solid #000;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

.flex {
   display:flex;
}

.icon:before {
   content: "✆";
}
```

```html
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <div class="flex">
            <span class="icon"></span>
            <span class="content">Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem Ipsum dolor and so on ...</span>
         </div>
      </td>
      <td>
            <span class="content">LongWordWithoutWhitespace</span>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

***Edit 2:*** *I was able to reproduce an issue with the solution of Paulie_D, please look at the snippet below:*

```css
table {
    width: 90%; 
    border: 1px solid #000;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

.flex {
   display:flex;
}

.icon:before {
   content: "✆";
}

.content {
   flex-grow: 1;
   flex-shrink: 0;
   flex-basis: 0; 
}
```

```html
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <div class="flex">
            <span class="icon"></span>
            <span class="content">Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem Ipsum</span>
         </div>
      </td>
      <td>
         <div class="flex">
            <span>Content here</span>
         </div>
      </td>
            <td>
         <div class="flex">
            <span>and_some_long_content_here</span>
         </div>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Dumb question, but do i need a prefix or something like that?

Comment: There are a lot of problems with flexbox in IE11. Check the known issues tab here: http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Comment: No need for prefix on IE11, IE10 need `-ms-`

Answer (score 4):

This is because IE does not accept `auto` as a value for `flex-basis` which is the default.

If you change this to `flex-basis:0` it works as expected.

```css
table {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  /* flex-wrap: wrap; breaks the layout in Chrome, too */
}

.icon:before {
  content: "✆";
}

.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="flex">
        <span class="icon"></span>
        <span class="content">Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem Ipsum dolor and so on ...</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, Paulie_D, the only problem now is, like in the answer from LGSon, that the width of the columns does not seem to depend on the content anymore, which causes some overflows.

Answer (score 3):

IE need `table-layout: fixed` to play along.

```css
table {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  table-layout: fixed
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.icon:before {
  content: "✆";
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="flex">
        <span class="icon"></span>
        <span class="content">Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem Ipsum dolor and so on ...</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

Updated after question edit

Since a flex items `min-width` defaults to `auto` it will not shrink beyond its content. By using `min-width: 0`, or as in below sample `overflow: hidden` (will also clip the text, which `min-width` doesn't), it will be able to shrink beyond its content.

The `word-wrap: break-word` will make `td`'s content wrap long words.

```css
table {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.icon:before {
  content: "✆";
}

td {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
.content {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <div class="flex">
            <span class="icon"></span>
            <span class="content">Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem Ipsum dolor and so on ...</span>
         </div>
      </td>
      <td>
            <span class="content">LongWordWithoutWhitespace</span>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That is a pretty good one, the only problem now is, that the table columns dont depend on the actual content width anymore, which causes some other issues like overflowing text

Comment: @MatthiasS. Well, that is the exact issue, as IE won't recognize the width as the other browsers do ... one of IE's many bugs. Paulie_D's solution might work better for you.

Comment: Just tried both, but in the end it doesnt even matter ;-) No, being serious again, the solution of Paulie_D is causing the exact same issue =/

Comment: @MatthiasS. Could you elaborate some more with what the follow up issue look like?

Comment: Working on it, should be updated in a few minutes :)

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: @MatthiasS. Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks, even if breaking the word is not exactly as perfect as just stretching the columns (like chrome does by default), it seems to be the best workaround for this cruel IE Bug. Definetly helped me!

Comment: @MatthiasS. Well, as being a _bug fix_ for IE I think it is as good as it gets :) ... also, and not knowing how complex your flex elements will be, very often an `inline-block` solution can do similar things Flexbox can, which might be another workaround.

Comment: Let's say its a bit more complex than the example above ;) I'm now at the point, where I try to find a solution without flexbox at all

Comment: @MatthiasS. Maybe a case for Stackoverflow ;)

Comment: We will see, how far Ican get for myself, but yeah, maybe ;) Thanks for the effort with this question!